# Laravel 5.7 throws Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message error on calling update function

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7

I've been using ajax post to update my database information with success using Laravel 5.2. The view, controller and model are in place but as I implement it using Laravel 5.7, I got this error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ > MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message.

Is there any changes or adjustment I have to make using Laravel 5.7? Please help. Thank you

**View**:

```
<form class="update-member-form" id="update-member-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="primary_id" value="">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Member ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_id" class="form-control" id="member_id" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="editMember_name" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Middle Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mname" class="form-control" id="editMember_mname" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="editMember_lname" value="" required>
      </div>
</form>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()" >Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-update-member">Save updates</button>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".btn-update-member").click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      $.post("{{ url('/updatemember') }}", $("#update-member-form").serialize(), function(data){

            if(data.notify == "Success"){

                swal({
                      title: "Record successfully updated",
                      text: "Message will close in 2 seconds",
                      type: "success",
                      timer: 2000
                    });

            } else{

              console.log(data.notify);

            }


          },"json"); 

      });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/updatemember', 'MembersController@update');
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    $updateMember = Member::where( 'id', $request['id'] )
                          ->update( $request->all() );

       if( $updateMember ){

         $notification = "Success";

       } else{

         $notification = "Failed";

       }

     return json_encode( array( 'notify'=>$notification ) );
}
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your route is wrong because you pass `$id` as parameter in your update function so please update your view file also

```
Route::post('/updatemember', 'MembersController@update');
```

**change to**

```
Route::post('/updatemember/{id}', 'MembersController@update');
```

Comment: It returns 404
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. error

Comment: Laravel 5.7 already put that paramater $id in default. I did not put that as parameter.

Comment: so please remove $id form update function and please check

Answer (score 0):

If you already put parameter then remove id from method:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $updateMember = Member::where( 'id', $request['id'] )
                          ->update( $request->all() );    
       if( $updateMember ){    
         $notification = "Success";    
       } else{    
         $notification = "Failed";    
       }    
     return json_encode( array( 'notify'=>$notification ) );
}
```

**OR**

You have to change route to:

```
Route::post('/updatemember/{id}', 'MembersController@update');
```

and also in js:

```
$.post("{{ url('/updatemember/yourid') }}", $("#update-member-form").serialize(), function(data){
            if(data.notify == "Success"){
             ...
            } else{
              console.log(data.notify);
            }
```

EDIT :
You have to pass value in id input which is empty:

```
<input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="primary_id" value="">
```

Comment: dump you request object and check all params you are getting or not

Comment: set id as `value`  insted of `value=""` in id input

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: check you are getting id in request or not

Comment: change `$request['id']` to `$request->id`

Comment: It returns the right id but can't successfully save the updates

Comment: What is happening here? :(

Comment: Check `$fillable` array  in `Member` Model.

Comment: I think this is the problem ->update( $request->all() ); Is this correct?

Comment: Tried inserting using this one ->update(['delayed' => 1]); and it works. Just thinking if how could I insert $request->all() this way?

Comment: add column names in $fillable arrray in model

Comment: I already put in there all of the columns protected $fillable = ['member_id','fname','mname','lname','extension','date_of_birth','marital_status','sex','home_address','email_address','contact_number','photo_url','member_type','member_status'];

Comment: But this one is working $updateMember = Member::where( 'id', $request['id'] )
                              ->update( ['fname' =>  $request['fname'] ] ); The problem is I have to do it one by one. tedious

Comment: Okay. i will update answer if i got or done example of this.

Comment: In my  Laravel 5.2 project, this works ->update( $request->all() ); but now in Laravel 5.7, it doesn't worked. Thanks man for helping.

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the you are using POST but actually you have to perform PUT To fix this add

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

after form you just paste this

and don't forget

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets start
Member.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{
    // if you changed the primary key id you need to set it here
    protected $primaryKey = 'primary_id';
    protected $guarded = [];
    // Also to work it with route model binding you need this too
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'primary_id';
    }
}
```

Then web.php

```
// Get The Form name param has to be the same name as the controller variable
Route::get('/members/{member}/edit', 'MembersController@edit');
// Patch the form. 
// Not post because you are not creating. 
// Not put because you are not replacing. 
// Patch because you are updating 
Route::patch('/members/{member}/edit', 'MembersController@update')->name('member.update');
```

Then MembersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Member;

class MembersController extends Controller
{
    // Bind the route to the model. It throws 404 if the member does not exit;
    public function edit(Request $request, Member $member)
    {
        return view('members.edit', compact('member'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Member $member)
    {
        die('i am here update');
    }
}
```

And of course the form

```
<form class="update-member-form" id="update-member-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @method('PATCH') 
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Member ID:</label>
      <input type="text" name="member_id" class="form-control" id="member_id" value="{{$member->member_id}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="editMember_name" value="{{$member->fname}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Middle Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="mname" class="form-control" id="editMember_mname" value="{{$member->mname}}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="editMember_lname" value="{{$member->lname}}" required>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()" >Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-update-member">Save updates</button>
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $(".btn-update-member").click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  $.post("{{ route('member.update', $member->primary_id) }}", $("#update-member-form").serialize(), function(data){

        if(data.notify == "Success"){

            swal({
                  title: "Record successfully updated",
                  text: "Message will close in 2 seconds",
                  type: "success",
                  timer: 2000
                });

        } else{

          console.log(data.notify);

        }


      },"json"); 

  });
</script>
```

Of course you can avoid route model binding and get the id from input field or just as an int id from the route and then query through the db check if the member exits and bla bla bla.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code works for me. By just adding the `->except('_token')`

```
 Member::where( 'id', $request['id'])->update($request->except('_token'));
```